# This JS code finds the index of the highest value in an array but how does it work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The line of code in quesion:

```
let largest = arr.reduce((a,v,i) => v > a[1] ? [i,v] : a, [-1,0]);
```

I am confused mainly by this part `a, [-1,0]`, I don't understand this syntax. What is `a` doing before a comma?

Comment: Do you know how the ternary operator works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Here's how it looks with a lot of the shorthand expanded:

```js
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue, index) => {
  if (currentValue > accumulator[1]) {
    return([index, currentValue])
  } else {
    return(accumulator)
  }
}

let largest = accumulator.reduce(reducer, [-1, 0])
```

#### What's happening:

`Array.prototype.reduce()` has two arguments, the callback function and the initial value. That's where the `[-1, 0]` is coming from, that's the "initial value" that will be passed as the "accumulator" to the callback function on the first iteration.

The shortest shorthand for a function in javascript is `() => value` where "value" represents the return value of the function—no parenthesis are required. In this example that return value is a ternary statement: `condition ? return if true : return if false`. Essentially, because they're using a single line to produce a single value, there's no parenthesis or braces required around the function (which ends at the `a`).

The callback function you pass to `Array.reduce()` can take three arguments, `(accumulator, currentValue, index)`.

The key here is in the initial value, which is `[index, value]`, which keeps track of both until iteration is finished, in which case just the final value is returned.

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing description as to what is happening in the code.

Comment: Thx I am aware of the ternary operator and the reduce function but the explanation is appreciated. Mainly the last bit: .reduce(reducer, [-1,0]) was what I needed clarified.

Answer (score 3):

The array that comes after the comma is a *second argument* to [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). The code there is equivalent to

```
let largest = arr.reduce(
  (a,v,i) => {
    return v > a[1] ? [i,v] : a;
  },
  [-1,0] // second argument
);
```

On very iteration, the accumulator is an array composed of 2 values. The value returned from the callback becomes the new accumulator in the next iteration. The value returned on the last iteration becomes the result of the whole `.reduce()` expression - the `largest`.

So what `return v > a[1] ? [i,v] : a;` does inside a `.reduce()` callback is it'll go through the array and find the item with the highest `v` - once the `[i, v]` of that becomes the accumulator, the accumulator will stay as that array until iteration finishes.

Answer (score 2):

This is more easily understood if formalized and expanded:

```js
let reducer = (a,v,i) => {
  if (v > a[1])
    return [i,v];

  return a
};

let largest = arr.reduce(reducer, [-1,0]);
```

Where now the reducer function argument is pretty clear.